# Tailwind CSS font size works, but margins and borders don't. Did I install it incorrectly?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to style my webpage using tailwind css -- the whole thing. But my immediate goal is to style some text on some inputs and buttons using borders. This is where I discovered that my Tailwind is configured wrong.

Because the way that this "doesn't work" is quite vague its difficult to diagnose with Googling. I found one result that suggested adding `border` because without a `border` the code `border-black` has no `border` to apply itself to. But I did that and nothing changed. Additionally I can *see* that in the browser, there is no margin being added.

I expect that the following code should give a margin and black border to my button. It does not.

```
function Button({ label, action }) {
    return (
        <button
            className="border-2 border-black mt-3 text-2xl"
            onClick={() => {
                action();
            }}
        >
            {label}
        </button>
    );
}

export default Button;
```

Here is the code as it is present in my browser: `<button class="border-2 border-black mt-3 text-2xl">Next</button>` so we know the stylings have reached the button.

Additionally I see that the fonts have updated since I added Tailwind CSS (because tailwind overrides default font styling with its own), **and** the following styling **does** work:

`<h2 className="text-2xl">Foo</h2> // the text is actually bigger, confirming that tailwind css is applying something`

Is there something I have to configure to make Tailwind reach my code?

Here is `tailwind.config.js` in its default state, sitting in the parent directory alongside `/src`:

```
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {}
    },
    plugins: []
};
```

Running `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch` doesn't help either **and** I do have `<link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">` in my `index.html` file [the way its described in the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

`package.json` because I presume someone will ask:

```
{
  "name": "westland",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

Help please & thank you!

edit: Testing reveals `border-red-500` works but `border-black` does not.

Comment: i think it's not overwriting the CSS, add this `important: true`  to your tailwind.config.js/json

Comment: Tried, it didn't change anything.

Comment: I guess I had to refresh my site or something because it works now. Thanks @callmeizaz

Comment: yepp once you make any changes to config file you'll need to restart the server

Comment: I see you use react. If your button component has an jsx extension, you might need to add that to the content property in the tailwind config.

Comment: Gabe figured it out. I should've seen that. It was the missing `.jsx` in the `tailwind.config.js` If you come back and post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

If `border-2` is not working, you can also use another alternative ,that is `ring-1` and `ring-black`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```